# How to install Mobisystem OfficeSuite on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, wine, windows-7, microsoft

I am trying to use [OfficeSuite](https://www.officesuitenow.com) installer for Windows to install OfficeSuite on Ubuntu 16.04

I have configured my wine to use windows 7 and installed microsoft.net framework 4.5. Still when I try to install OfficeSuite I get the error .Net not install and installer asks to install it by itself. When I click on Yes, it shows installation failed.

Can anybody guide me on how to do this?